# Как имитировать нажатие клавиши Z внутри события JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://213.27.32.135:8100"); 
ws.onmessage = function(event) 
{
  Как здесь нажать клавишу "Z"?
}
```

Comment: зачем именно Z? почему просто не сделать DEBUG_FLAG и при тестировании ориентироваться на него?

Comment: я только начинаю работать с JS и не знаю что это DEBUG_FLAG, а Z мне нужна для того что бы в моем флеш ролике нажать на кнопку

Comment: DEBUG_FLAG - это своя собственная переменная принимающая значение true/false...... когда true - значит нажали, когда false - не нажали

Comment: и как это совместить с моей задачей? у меня во флеш есть кнопка "авто", которую клиент может нажать мышью или с клавиатуры "Z". мне нужно что б по команде от сервера, режим "авто" отключался, для этого нажать "Z"

Comment: я без понятия как ты это у себя реализовываешь в итоге...Как ты там манипулируешь с клавишами.. но ты пишешь `Как имитировать нажатие клавиши` - я тебе написал

Comment: dispatchEvent, но вот не факт, что с flash это прокатит.

Comment: я просто пояснил, для чего, чтоб понятнее было. а где написано, как имитировать? может пример небольшой, если не сложно

Comment: Не надо имитировать нажатие кнопки, надо просто выполнить действие.

Comment: я сделал имитацию(исправлено в ответе), но кнопка не нажалась, хотя алерт выполняется и при моем событии и при нажатии на Z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вот так имитирует, alert  показывает и при нажатии на Z и при событии onmessage

```
var e = jQuery.Event( "keypress", { which: 122 } );
window.onkeypress = function(event)
{
    if(event.which == 122){alert("ok")}
}

var ws = new WebSocket("ws://213.27.32.135:8100"); 
ws.onmessage = function(event) 
{
  КакjQuery( здесь"body" нажать).trigger( клавишуe "Z"?);
}
```

может кто подсказать почему флеш не реагирует на такое нажатие?

Comment: флэш сам по себе, почему он должен реагировать на jQuery с которым никак не связан?

Comment: когда я нажимаю на клавиатуре Z, кнопка во флеш нажимается, когда я имитирую нажатие в javascript это не то же самое нажатие?

Comment: Нет, не то же самое.

Comment: а как сделать тоже самое?

Comment: в общем случае никак. И это хорошо, так как позволяет отличить программное событие от события с реальной клавиатуры. В случае с флэшкой, если она твоя - то надо вытянуть наружу функцию которая выполняется по нажатию `Z` и вызвать ее напрямую из js, без всяких trigger. Если доступа к коду флэшки нет, то, скорее всего, никак.